# How to read .xhprof files?

Tags: php, performance, profiling, cpu-usage, xhprof

I have .xhprof files generated from XHProf and UProfiler.

Tried using SugarCrm XHProf Viewer and UProfiler viewer, but both of them doesn't read .xhprof files.

Do I have to do any conversion to read this reports?

Answer (score 3):

I am maintaining [XHProf](https://github.com/patrickallaert/xhprof) since it is not maintained by Facebook anymore.

As part of the project, there is an [`xhprof_html`](https://github.com/patrickallaert/xhprof/tree/php7/xhprof_html) sub-directory. If you can reach its `index.php` directly from a URL (maybe you will have to create a separate *VirtualHost* and/or putting it somewhere under your *document root*), then it should show you a list of profiles that have been generated (by default, it is in the temporary directory (`/tmp`?)).